# Excel 2016 - Passing Date Parameter Values into SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, parameters

I have the following SQL statement, I would like to replace the date values with parameters passed from a Table in Excel (to make it easier for end user):

```
SELECT * FROM

( SELECT TEMP.BNH_PROCESSING_GRP, TEMP.BNH_SUPPLIER_NO, TEMP.BNH_PROCESSING_FLAG, TEMP.BNH_CREATE_DT, TEMP.BNH_TIER1_USER_ID, TEMP.BNH_TIER1_NAME, TEMP.BNH_TIER1_MAINT_DT, TEMP.BNH_TIER2_USER_ID, TEMP.BNH_TIER2_NAME,
     TEMP.BNH_TIER2_MAINT_DT, TEMP.BNH_TIER3_USER_ID, TEMP.BNH_TIER3_NAME,

     ( SELECT MAX(ABA_bank_H.BNH_TIER3_MAINT_DT) FROM ABA_bank_H WHERE ABA_bank_H.BNH_SUPPLIER_NO = TEMP.BNH_SUPPLIER_NO ) AS T3DATE,

     TEMP.BNH_BANK_NO, TEMP.BNH_BRANCH_NO, TEMP.BNH_REFERENCE_ROLL_NO, TEMP.BNH_CHECKING_SAVINGS, TEMP.BNH_T_RECORD_TYPE, TEMP.BNH_BANK_CONTROL_DIGIT, TEMP.BNH_ROUTING_TRANSIT, TEMP.BNH_ACCOUNT_NO, TEMP.BNH_IBAN,
     TEMP.BNH_SWIFT_CD, TEMP.BNH_ACCT_DESC

FROM ABA_bank_H AS TEMP

WHERE TEMP.BNH_PROCESSING_GRP = 'CZE' AND TEMP.BNH_PROCESSING_FLAG='O'

UNION

SELECT BNH_PROCESSING_GRP, BNH_SUPPLIER_NO, BNH_PROCESSING_FLAG, BNH_CREATE_DT, BNH_TIER1_USER_ID, BNH_TIER1_NAME, BNH_TIER1_MAINT_DT, BNH_TIER2_USER_ID, BNH_TIER2_NAME,
     BNH_TIER2_MAINT_DT, BNH_TIER3_USER_ID, BNH_TIER3_NAME, BNH_TIER3_MAINT_DT AS T3DATE, BNH_BANK_NO, BNH_BRANCH_NO, BNH_REFERENCE_ROLL_NO, BNH_CHECKING_SAVINGS,
     BNH_T_RECORD_TYPE, BNH_BANK_CONTROL_DIGIT, BNH_ROUTING_TRANSIT, BNH_ACCOUNT_NO, BNH_IBAN, BNH_SWIFT_CD, BNH_ACCT_DESC

FROM ABA_bank_H

WHERE BNH_PROCESSING_GRP = 'CZE' AND BNH_PROCESSING_FLAG='H'
)
ABA_bank_H
WHERE T3DATE BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31'
Order by BNH_PROCESSING_GRP, BNH_SUPPLIER_NO, BNH_PROCESSING_FLAG, BNH_CREATE_DT
```

I have a Table created in a separate Tab called 'Parameters'

```
Parameter   Value

StartDate   2018-03-01

EndDate         2018-03-31
```

and I have the following Get parameters function:

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=
if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
Value
```

I added the following to the Advanced Editor of my Query:

```
sStartDate = fnGetParameter("StartDate"),
sEndDate = fnGetParameter("EndDate"),
```

and changed the SQL statement as follows:

```
...WHERE T3DATE BETWEEN  'sStartDate' AND 'sEndDate' #(lf)  Order by...
```

I get an error I think with date formatting but I dont know how to resolve this:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string."

Can you help me fix my issue or maybe recommend a different approach?

Comment: Other than SQL, what language is this that runs the Excel operations? Please tag it.

Comment: Is this M code you have included? Are your excel source cells formatted as date? Pretty sure I had something similar once with Powerquery and a function that looked like yours.

Comment: Yes M code. I have the format as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm but I have tried text as well because I notice that Excel looks at my date as a number 43160, which cant be good.